Eslint single quote rule not applying in vue template
Why doesn't eslint single quote rule apply inside vue template?
Relatively new to vue and codebase that I am working on does not have prettier (yet). I just wonder if this is a linter limitation. Or, what complementary plugins should I use for the rule to work inside the template?
.vue (I don't get a warning here. It should be t('...'))
<template>
    <span class="myClass">{{ t("myLabel") }}</span>
</template>

eslint rule
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: ['warn', 'single'],
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['dist/']
}

package.json script
"lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.vue src/"


I don't use quotes as an eslint rule since it's been deprecated in ESLint v8.53.0.  I can only suggest maybe a plugin, e.g. eslint-plugin-prettier.  prettier singleQuote rule works well for me in .vue files.
